# Why an MDB class cannot be final

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee, ejb

This [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbpo/index.html) says that Message Driven Bean `class cannot be defined as abstract or final.` What is the reason for this? Why this class cannot be closed for extensions?

UPDATE:
I test this on JBoss Eap 6.3, And what I noted is MDB doesn't get fired though there are messages in the queue, But I couldn't find any error logs regarding this.

Comment: This is a good question. The EJB 3.1 spec doesn't say anything more than the tutorial.

Comment: I tried doing this, And what I noted is MDB doesn't get fired though there are messages in the queue, But I couldn't find any error logs regarding this. I tried this on JBoss Eap 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let containers instrument the instancess - which allows them to inject dependencies and do other tricks. Good article on instrumentation - http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-instrumentation/. Containers may do it in many different ways of course.

Comment: Its not clear enough for me to accept this as the answer. How inject dependencies affect class being final?

Comment: in most cases it's impossible to insturment final class. Look, for example at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437323/how-can-i-create-dynamic-proxy-for-final-class, it's about http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/, the library used by hibernate to do instrumentation. Although I never cared too much about such a deep details, so you may want to find more reliable sources :)